# Using PCL3e escape sequences on an HP Officejet Pro 8630 to duplex on the long edge

Tags: printing, duplex, hp-officejet, escape-sequences, pcl

I'm trying to print raw, plain ASCII text (e.g. IETF RFCs, which contain form-feed characters for automatic pagination) by sending it directly to port 9100 on my [HP Officejet Pro 8630](http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-officejet-pro-8630-e-all-in-one-printer). The specifications state that the printer supports PCL3e and PCL3GUI, which for the most part are undocumented unlike PCL5 or PCL6.

In an attempt to gain more control over the printing process, I'm prefixing the text to be printed with PCL escape sequences, by opening a raw PuTTY session to port 9100 on the printer and entering them manually before pasting the complete text of the document.

Using [this PCL reference](http://www.pclviewer.com/resources/reference/), I managed to make the printer print from the second paper tray using the code `<ESC>&l4H`. However, contrary to the reference, both `<ESC>&l1S` and `<ESC>&l2S` cause the printer to duplex on the *short* edge, which is not what I want.

How do I get the printer to duplex on the *long* edge using only PCL3e escape sequences?

Comment: First idea to hit my brain (which may be a crappy one): have you tried `<ESC>&l0O` or `<ESC>&l1O` to set Portrait/Landscape modes, respectively?

Comment: Actually, it seems the thing to try might be to rotate the second duplexed page 180° with `<ESC>&l2O` or `<ESC>&a180P`. I take it you're breaking between pages with `<ESC>&a0G`? Are you using the CRD command (`<ESC>*g#W`)? If so, then you might need to use the reload media command `<ESC>&-2H` (it's what gutenprint uses internally, check their source code).

Comment: Requesting specific orientations or page rotation did not help.